# How to explore the local active directory?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, active-directory, active-directory-explorer

Question: On Windows7, how can I explore the local active directory ?

I mean getting all directory entries I would see when I execute this code:

```
Dim AD As New System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName & ",computer")
```

I have found a systernals tool, called activedirectory explorer,
(http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963907.aspx)
 and I run it as complete administrator (root), but it always says "server not working/running".

But the server obviously works, since I can query it from .net...
and it's definitely local, since I plugged the network connection

Answer (score 2):

If you install the administration tools pack (from [MS Downloads](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=7d2f6ad7-656b-4313-a005-4e344e43997d)) you will get all the Server MMC snapins available in Add/Remove Windows Components (from Programs and Features).

This includes the AD administration tools.